# libpqxx double free detected

Tags: c++, postgresql, libpqxx

I need to use PostgreSQL C++ library. I simply include pqxx/pqxx in my helloworld code but I don't use it! When I've run it I've got an error:

"db:free(): double free detected in tcache 2"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pqxx/pqxx>  //<------- causes db:free(): double free detected in tcache 2
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    std::cout << "Hello world" ;
    return 0;
}
```

I installed libpqxx from master branch of its github repository, with configure, make, make install.

I have a debian unstable and I also have an installed libpq-dev and a libpq5 package. Documentation said:
"Do I need libpq when I use libpqxx? Yes; libpqxx is built on top of libpq."

I've compiled it with g++ main.cpp -lpqxx -lpq

How can I eliminate this problem?

thx,

Zamek

Comment: Do you get it just from this code? What version of g++ just to be sure I am using the exact same version? Also why the master branch and not a release?

Comment: The key word here, it seems, is "unstable".

Comment: it is g++ (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0. I tried to use 7.1.1 branch as documentation suggested but after I run configure make gave an error: 
strconv.cxx:595:41: error: ‘dumb_stringstream’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘to_dumb_stringstream’?
  595 | inline std::string to_dumb_stringstream(dumb_stringstream<F> &s, F value)

Answer (score 0):

Do please file bugs for these problems at https://github.com/jtv/libpqxx !

Any idea what software actually generated the error?  It doesn't happen for me, and I routinely test libpqxx using various tools to detect these things.

That said, I'll run a test against sid later today and see whether I can reproduce it.  Valgrind used to generate some false positives along these lines, so hopefully it's just that.

Comment: Tried it just now in a fresh debian:unstable image and didn't see the problem.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce the problem with 7.7.1 either.  :-(  Could it be that there's something "unlucky" on your system that's breaking things?  For example, perhaps there are two copies of libpqxx on the system?